# Shape traffic flowing through dd-wrt router

Tags: networking, iptables, dd-wrt, tc

I am working on an experiment in which several devices connect to each other via a wireless network. I want to be able to shape the traffic between the devices, i.e., control the bandwidth, latency, packet loss, etc. in order to test my setup under different network conditions.

I have a netgear R7000 wireless router that I updated to run DD WRT and I manage to get [ATC](http://facebook.github.io/augmented-traffic-control/) running on it. However, ATC seems to shape only the traffic flowing from the internet to the devices and vice-versa but not the local traffic between the devices. Any idea on how could I go about this?